# c# .dat file assign to variable

Tags: c#, file

how can i assign a to a variable, which is located at the same project, for example at my project i created a folder named App_Data and for example the file is file.dat , how can i assign the file at a variable,.. for example:

```
var file = App_Data/file.dat
```

I need it to be assigned to a variable because i will be using that variable as a parameter to a method,.. it used to be :

```
var file= HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("/App_Data/file.dat");
```

but now i want the path to be at the same project

if it should be absolute path it should be fine too

Comment: Er... use a `string`? Maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: @MatthewWatson i have a file, and i need it to be stored on a variable var storehere = file.dat; i dont need the path to be at storehere , i need the file itself or the content of the file to be on storehere

Comment: You want the contents of the file to be stored in a variable, but you don't want to read the file... Is that what you're saying?

Comment: [How to: Read text from a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx)

Comment: @MatthewWatson sorry about that, i only meant not to store the location or stream it

Comment: @AlexFilipovici Does it work on .dat files? and does absolute path work for the location of the file?

Comment: Why shouldn't it work for 'dat file? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the file using one of the available methods (Streams, Readers, etc).

The easiest would be:

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(fileNameAndPath);
```

where the variable `fileNameAndPath` contains the full path and file name to the file as described by Darin Dimitrov.

Comment: is it possible for me to use a relative path instead, so it would still work even i transfer the library to other solutions?

Comment: You can use relative paths if you want. I would, however, always try to make sure to use either `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` to map the filename or `Path.GetDirectory(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` to determine the path of the currently executing assembly, so you can compose an absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

The `MapPath` should give you the absolute location of the file on disk from a relative url to the root of your website:

```
var absoluteFileLocation = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/file.dat");
```

This should return something like:

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite\App_Data\file.dat
```

---

UPDATE:

It looks like you are trying to retrieve the contents of the file, not the location. Here's how this could be done:

```
var absoluteFileLocation = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/file.dat");
string fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(absoluteFileLocation);
```

Comment: I dont need to store the location i need the content itself to the stored at the variable, and the file is located at the same project

Comment: and the problem now is, the file is not in a website, but just in a class library, in a App_Data folder

Comment: @sclang, then simply use the `File.ReadAllText` method. This will work for text files. If the format of your file is binary you might read it as a byte array using the `ReadAllBytes` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your intention isn't exactly clear, anyway:

if you want file stats:

```
System.IO.File file = new System.IO.File("~/App_Data/file.dat");
```

if you want the file content use:

```
    public static string readFileContent(String filename)
    {
        try
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename))
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch { return String.Empty; }
    }
```